# Organizing JavaScript Variables in VsCode?

Tags: javascript, variables, visual-studio-code, code-organization

Looking for a way to organize variables inside vsCode. Similar to the way that you can collapse a function in the workspace, I would like to be able to collapse a long list of variables ...

```js
var x = 1 
var y = 2
var z = 3
var w = 4
var v = 5
//etc.
```

Comment: this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/18805 - WebStorm does it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 **hacks**:

1. **Code Block** (`important!` be careful with variables scope)
2. **Object Literal**

Example of Code Block:

```
{
    const x = 10;
    const y = 20;
}
```

Example of Object Literal:

```
const variablesNamespace = {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
}

console.log(variablesNamespace.x) // output 10
```

[image]